# gather and spread with dplyr easy example

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, spread

I am trying to get the philosophy of gather and spread write.
if you have a a data frame that looks like this:

```
group=c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
time =c(10,20,30,10,20,30)
value=c(20,40,80,10,10,20)

data= data.frame(group,time,value)

group time value
  A   10    20
  A   20    40
  A   30    80
  B   10    10
  B   20    10
  B   30    20
```

How can you get here

```
A   B   time
20 10    10
40 10    20
80 20    30
```

Comment: You can use `tidyr::spread` like this:
`tidyr::spread(data, group, value)`. However, `pivot_wider` is a more flexible alternative to `spread`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = value)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   time     A     B
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    10    20    10
#2    20    40    10
#3    30    80    20
```